# How to pass MouseMoved event to WebView content?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

We are using the webview control in a WinRT XAML app. The problem we are facing is that MouseMove event is not passed to the html when using touch, while it is normally passed when using mouse.

When using touch the events passed during touch-move-release are:

- MouseDown
- MouseUp

while with mouse they are:

- MouseDown
- MouseMove
- MouseUp

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not yet :( for the time being we gave up and used an alternative solution.